# If statement trouble in Python

Tags: python, if-statement, rfid

I am interfacing a RFID sensor (MFRC522) with a Raspberry Pi. I am currently testing the whole system out. Basically, once the RFID tag is swiped it outputs a number associated with it. I want the python code to read in the RFID number and compare it with the variable 'a.' When I attempt to do this, though, I am getting an invalid syntax error for the 'if' statement and I am not sure why. I am new to Python.

```
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO

from mfrc522 import SimpleMFRC522

GPIO.setwarings(False)

a = 699562167785

reader = SimpleMFRC522()

try:
    id = reader.read()
    print (id)

if id == a
    print ("Awesome")

finally:
    GPIO.cleanup()
```

Comment: You're missing `except:` for your `try`.

Comment: You're missing the `:` at the end of the `if` line.

Comment: Is the `if` statement supposed to be in the `try` block? Then it needs to be indented.

Comment: Okay, I get the same error when I have the ':' at the end of 'if id == a'

Comment: Yes, Barmar you are correct! I have figured it out

Comment: Please also be aware that 'id' is a built in function in Python, you are effectively overwriting it, which may never pose a problem as I have not used id in over a decade, but you never know...

Answer (score 0):

Indentation:

Use tabs to indent the 'if' code inside 'Try', put the ':' after the comparison,   and add

```
except:
    pass
```

Before Finally

Answer (score 0):

do this :

```
try:
   id = reader.read()
   print (id)
   if (id == a):
   print ("Awesome")
finally:
   GPIO.cleanup()
```